# Remap request to different local path

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I'd like to serve multiple subdomains with my webserver:

example.com
projects.example.com
blog.example.com
wiki.example.com
...

The document root is being set as follows:

```
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias   *.example.com
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%0/public"
```

This works as it automatically sets the document root to the corresponding subdomain. My next requirement however, is that it should detect if the `public` folder in the document root even exists, and if not, serve the file from one directory earlier.

Most of my applications are written with Laravel, so they come with a `public` folder, however sometimes I just want to quickly create a new script that doesn't have `public` or deploy external software that doesn't.

Therefore the document root for `example.com` (which just serves a static `index.html` and `style.css`) should be `/var/www/example.com/` rather than `/var/www/example.com/public`. I tried this via rewrite rules:

```
<If "!-d '/var/www/' . %{HTTP_HOST} . '/public'">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ "/var/www/%{HTTP_HOST}" [L,QSA]
</If>
```

This is the result of the rewrite error log:

```
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] pass through /
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] [perdir *If/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.com -> /var/www/example.com/public/
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] [perdir *If/] applying pattern '^' to uri '/var/www/example.com/public/'
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] [perdir *If/] rewrite '/var/www/example.com/public/' -> '/var/www/example.com'
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 32153] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 62.159.226.12:27139] 62.159.226.12 - - [example.com/sid#7f6588016340][rid#7f6587f810a0/initial] [perdir *If/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /var/www/example.com [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

As you can see, it maps it correctly, but for some reason doesn't serve the file from there (I assume it's because it doesn't append `index.html` or anything the like).

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the core sees that non-existent public/ and splits it out of the current filename and into PATH_INFO.  Even the [DPI] flag won't help here because it removes PATH_INFO at the last minute as a side-effect of the rewrite.

Unfortunately this change where you try to ditch PATH_INFO is caught in the "loop detection" of mod_rewrite and mistaken for no change in filename.

You should invert your logic so there is never stray PATH_INFO injected. The rewrite will then optionally add the public suffix instead of removing it.

This also allows you to drop the negation and really the entire  by just using a typical -d test in RewriteCond.

Comment: Would you have an example for me? I tried it with [this config](http://pastebin.com/i7vkfJ16) which to my understanding is what you suggested. It still results in a loop detection. If I use the `END` flag for the `RewriteRule` it works as expected, but obviously doesn't load any more rewrite rules from my .htaccess and as such the routes of the applications are broken where a `public` folder exists

Comment: Here's an example of the error log (with `rewrite:trace3` level) for when I use it without the `[END]` flag: http://pastebin.com/c6KDdh5b